# Hazelcast object equals for replace method callingfrom client

Tags: java, serialization, equals, hazelcast, in-memory-data-grid

I have configured hazelcast map with `in-memory-format: OBJECT`.
Now I am trying to use method `map.replace(key,oldValue,newVal)` assuming that it will use defined `equals` method in my class. But I make call not in hazelcast instance, but from separate client, aka from another jvm.
I tried to copy the same class to hazelcast application, but it doesn't work, it continue to compare by binary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will see that it works. Start your member with user code deployment

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
  Config config = new Config();
  UserCodeDeploymentConfig userCodeDeploymentConfig = 
  config.getUserCodeDeploymentConfig();
  userCodeDeploymentConfig.setEnabled(true);
        
  MapConfig mapConfig = config.getMapConfig("mymap");
  mapConfig.setInMemoryFormat(InMemoryFormat.OBJECT);
  HazelcastInstance hazelcastInstance = Hazelcast.newHazelcastInstance(config);
}
```

On the client side have a class as below

```java
package com.colak.datastructures.map;

public class Worker implements Serializable {

  String name;

  public Worker(String name) {
    this.name = name;
  }

  @Override
  public boolean equals(Object o) {
    if (this == o) return true;
    if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;
    Worker worker = (Worker) o;
    return Objects.equals(name, worker.name);
  }

  @Override
  public int hashCode() {
    return Objects.hash(name);
  }
}
```

Then start your client and deploy your domain object to member

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
  ClientConfig clientConfig = new ClientConfig();

  ClientUserCodeDeploymentConfig userCodeDeploymentConfig = 
    clientConfig.getUserCodeDeploymentConfig();
  userCodeDeploymentConfig.setEnabled(true);
  userCodeDeploymentConfig.addClass(com.colak.datastructures.map.Worker.class);

  HazelcastInstance hazelcastInstance = HazelcastClient.newHazelcastClient(clientConfig);

  IMap<Integer, Worker> map = hazelcastInstance.getMap("mymap");
  Worker worker1 = new Worker("john");
  Worker worker2 = new Worker("jane");

  int key = 1;
  map.put(key, worker1);
  Worker receivedWorker = map.get(key);

  if (!receivedWorker.equals(worker1)) {
    throw new IllegalStateException("receivedWorker is not equal to worker1");
  }

  map.replace(key, worker1, worker2); // Here replace workers for the same key
  receivedWorker = map.get(key);
  if (!receivedWorker.equals(worker2)) {
    throw new IllegalStateException("receivedWorker is not equal to worker2");
  }
}
```

You can see that worker1 is replaced with worker2 for key = 1